# In R, how to find the x for which f(x)=0.5

Tags: r, probability-density

I'm coding the birthday problem. My code:

```
> k = 100
> for (n in 1:100) {
+ prob =  1 - (0:(n-1))/365
+ k[n] = 1 - prod(prob) }
> plot(k)
```

I need to find the n for which its ~50% likely that two people share the same birthday. Any help? I tried googling but I can only find information about popular distributions.

Comment: Did you look at the [very detailed Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)?

Comment: I know how to do this by hand, I just don't know how to code it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already solved the problem.  You can find it "by eye", just type "k" and start counting.  Or you can have R find it for you.  The first day where the probability is greater than or equal to .5 is day number:

```
#TRUE is the maximum, pick the first of the ties:
which.max(k >= .5)
```

We can find the day with the minimum absolute difference from probability .5:

```
which.min(abs(k - .5))
```

Answer (score 4):

The "Birthday problem" already has two R functions designed to solve various forms of it:

```
birthday {stats}    R Documentation
Probability of coincidences

Description

Computes answers to a generalised birthday paradox problem. pbirthday computes the 
probability of a coincidence and qbirthday computes the smallest number of observations 
needed to have at least a specified probability of coincidence.

Usage

qbirthday(prob = 0.5, classes = 365, coincident = 2)
pbirthday(n, classes = 365, coincident = 2)
```

So the defaults for `qbirthday::

```
 > qbirthday()
 [1] 23
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following from the `stats` package...

```
 approx(k,1:100, xout = .5)
```

The above uses linear interpolation between the closest two provided points, which I may get jumped on because it is inaccurate...

But if we're doing the birthday problem I'm guessing we're learning about coding and not launching a rocket, so maybe its close enough?